# Why does this PHP code give this output?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I'm iterating through an array; my code is printing the array in its entirety on line 1, then printing each individual element in the loop below. How the array was generated shouldn't matter, and there is no code between where I print it whole and where I print it element-by-element.

The output of line 1 is correct; in the element-by-element printout generated by the loop, the last 2 elements contain the same data, the next-to-last element's data being repeated for the last element.

My original code is doing some additional processing in the loop (rather than providing output). What that code is doing is irrelevant, as that code is **commented out** and has been replaced by the simple code below as I attempt to debug this issue.

Why is the output being modified in the loop?

Here is the code in question:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($flat, true).'</pre>';
foreach ($flat AS $tu_pid => $details) {
    echo '<pre>'.$tu_pid.': '.print_r($details, true).'</pre>';
}
die();
```

For clarity, here is the last element, as presented by line 1:

```
[TARG-E] => stdClass Object
(
    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1033
            [discount] => 0.00000
            [charged] => 49.90
            [charged_bd] => 49.90
            [fm_disc] => 0.00000
            [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
            [member_pct] => 0.00000
            [tu_sale] => 0.00000
            [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
            [tu_price] => 49.90
            [cart] => 49.9
            [list] => 49.9
            [regular] => 49.9
            [sale] => 
            [sale_pct] => 0.00000
            [sale_start] => 
            [sale_end] => 
            [list_all] => 0.00
            [reg_all] => 0.00
            [reg_tu] => 0.00
            [reg_child] => 0.00
            [price_tu] => 0.00
            [tu_child] => 0.00
            [nesting] => 0
            [cu_type] => 0
            [use_price] => 1
            [root] => 1
            [royalty_item] => -1
        )

    [lineage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [owned] => 
    [products] => 
)
```

... and as presented by echo line within the loop:

```
TARG-E: stdClass Object
(
    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9745
            [discount] => 42.55975
            [charged] => 15.37
            [charged_bd] => 15.37
            [fm_disc] => 0.00000
            [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
            [member_pct] => 0.00000
            [tu_sale] => 32.95303
            [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
            [tu_price] => 15.37
            [cart] => 26.75174103
            [list] => 39.9
            [regular] => 39.9
            [sale] => 
            [sale_pct] => 0.00000
            [sale_start] => 
            [sale_end] => 
            [list_all] => 0.00
            [reg_all] => 0.00
            [reg_tu] => 0.00
            [reg_child] => 0.00
            [price_tu] => 0.00
            [tu_child] => 0.00
            [nesting] => 0
            [cu_type] => 0
            [use_price] => 1
            [root] => 
            [royalty_item] => 1019706
        )

    [lineage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PhotoGuide Set-6
                )

        )

    [owned] => 
    [products] => 
)
```

Here is the entire output of the code in question:

```
Array
(
    [PhotoGuide-Overview] => stdClass Object
        (
            [stats] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9744
                    [discount] => 42.55975
                    [charged] => 15.37
                    [charged_bd] => 15.37
                    [fm_disc] => 0.00000
                    [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
                    [member_pct] => 0.00000
                    [tu_sale] => 32.95303
                    [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
                    [tu_price] => 15.37
                    [cart] => 26.75174103
                    [list] => 39.9
                    [regular] => 39.9
                    [sale] => 
                    [sale_pct] => 0.00000
                    [sale_start] => 
                    [sale_end] => 
                    [list_all] => 0.00
                    [reg_all] => 0.00
                    [reg_tu] => 0.00
                    [reg_child] => 0.00
                    [price_tu] => 0.00
                    [tu_child] => 0.00
                    [nesting] => 0
                    [cu_type] => 0
                    [use_price] => 1
                    [root] => 
                    [royalty_item] => 1019706
                )

            [lineage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PhotoGuide Set-6
                        )

                )

            [owned] => 
            [products] => 
        )

    [PhotoGuide-Turkey] => stdClass Object
        (
            [stats] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9745
                    [discount] => 42.55975
                    [charged] => 15.37
                    [charged_bd] => 15.37
                    [fm_disc] => 0.00000
                    [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
                    [member_pct] => 0.00000
                    [tu_sale] => 32.95303
                    [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
                    [tu_price] => 15.37
                    [cart] => 26.75174103
                    [list] => 39.9
                    [regular] => 39.9
                    [sale] => 
                    [sale_pct] => 0.00000
                    [sale_start] => 
                    [sale_end] => 
                    [list_all] => 0.00
                    [reg_all] => 0.00
                    [reg_tu] => 0.00
                    [reg_child] => 0.00
                    [price_tu] => 0.00
                    [tu_child] => 0.00
                    [nesting] => 0
                    [cu_type] => 0
                    [use_price] => 1
                    [root] => 
                    [royalty_item] => 1019706
                )

            [lineage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PhotoGuide Set-6
                        )

                )

            [owned] => 
            [products] => 
        )

    [TARG-E] => stdClass Object
        (
            [stats] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1033
                    [discount] => 0.00000
                    [charged] => 49.90
                    [charged_bd] => 49.90
                    [fm_disc] => 0.00000
                    [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
                    [member_pct] => 0.00000
                    [tu_sale] => 0.00000
                    [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
                    [tu_price] => 49.90
                    [cart] => 49.9
                    [list] => 49.9
                    [regular] => 49.9
                    [sale] => 
                    [sale_pct] => 0.00000
                    [sale_start] => 
                    [sale_end] => 
                    [list_all] => 0.00
                    [reg_all] => 0.00
                    [reg_tu] => 0.00
                    [reg_child] => 0.00
                    [price_tu] => 0.00
                    [tu_child] => 0.00
                    [nesting] => 0
                    [cu_type] => 0
                    [use_price] => 1
                    [root] => 1
                    [royalty_item] => -1
                )

            [lineage] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [owned] => 
            [products] => 
        )

)

PhotoGuide-Overview: stdClass Object
(
    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9744
            [discount] => 42.55975
            [charged] => 15.37
            [charged_bd] => 15.37
            [fm_disc] => 0.00000
            [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
            [member_pct] => 0.00000
            [tu_sale] => 32.95303
            [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
            [tu_price] => 15.37
            [cart] => 26.75174103
            [list] => 39.9
            [regular] => 39.9
            [sale] => 
            [sale_pct] => 0.00000
            [sale_start] => 
            [sale_end] => 
            [list_all] => 0.00
            [reg_all] => 0.00
            [reg_tu] => 0.00
            [reg_child] => 0.00
            [price_tu] => 0.00
            [tu_child] => 0.00
            [nesting] => 0
            [cu_type] => 0
            [use_price] => 1
            [root] => 
            [royalty_item] => 1019706
        )

    [lineage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PhotoGuide Set-6
                )

        )

    [owned] => 
    [products] => 
)

PhotoGuide-Turkey: stdClass Object
(
    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9745
            [discount] => 42.55975
            [charged] => 15.37
            [charged_bd] => 15.37
            [fm_disc] => 0.00000
            [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
            [member_pct] => 0.00000
            [tu_sale] => 32.95303
            [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
            [tu_price] => 15.37
            [cart] => 26.75174103
            [list] => 39.9
            [regular] => 39.9
            [sale] => 
            [sale_pct] => 0.00000
            [sale_start] => 
            [sale_end] => 
            [list_all] => 0.00
            [reg_all] => 0.00
            [reg_tu] => 0.00
            [reg_child] => 0.00
            [price_tu] => 0.00
            [tu_child] => 0.00
            [nesting] => 0
            [cu_type] => 0
            [use_price] => 1
            [root] => 
            [royalty_item] => 1019706
        )

    [lineage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PhotoGuide Set-6
                )

        )

    [owned] => 
    [products] => 
)

TARG-E: stdClass Object
(
    [stats] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9745
            [discount] => 42.55975
            [charged] => 15.37
            [charged_bd] => 15.37
            [fm_disc] => 0.00000
            [coupon_pct] => 0.00000
            [member_pct] => 0.00000
            [tu_sale] => 32.95303
            [tu_shelf] => 0.00000
            [tu_price] => 15.37
            [cart] => 26.75174103
            [list] => 39.9
            [regular] => 39.9
            [sale] => 
            [sale_pct] => 0.00000
            [sale_start] => 
            [sale_end] => 
            [list_all] => 0.00
            [reg_all] => 0.00
            [reg_tu] => 0.00
            [reg_child] => 0.00
            [price_tu] => 0.00
            [tu_child] => 0.00
            [nesting] => 0
            [cu_type] => 0
            [use_price] => 1
            [root] => 
            [royalty_item] => 1019706
        )

    [lineage] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PhotoGuide Set-6
                )

        )

    [owned] => 
    [products] => 
)
```

Comment: what is PhotoGuide?

Comment: Can you provide an output of `var_dump($flat);`? Will allow us to test.